# error in java code of performing mouselistener

Tags: java, swing

hi i am performing a mouselistener action in my programm i am making a color jpanel when user click on panel it change its color but a line of code give some error like create a class e in your code but e is already declared as a instance of event class plz help me here is my code below.error is in this line "**panel.addMouseListener(e);**".

```
'import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class randomcolor extends JFrame{
    JPanel panel;
    public randomcolor (){
        panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(rancolor());
        add(panel);
    }

    event e =new event();
    panel.addMouseListener(e);

    public Color rancolor(){
        int r= (int) (Math.random()*256);
        int g= (int) (Math.random()*256);
        int b= (int) (Math.random()*256);
        return (new Color(r,g,b));
    }

    public class event implements MouseListener{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            panel.setBackground(rancolor());
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        randomcolor gui=new randomcolor();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setSize(300, 300);
        gui.setTitle("color panel");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Capitalize Event in `event e = new event()`. It should probably be `Event e = new Event()`. <del>The formatting in your code looks odd; that might be hiding other formatting errors too</del>.

Now that the code is properly formatted, I can see another problem; you probably meant to have

```
Event e = new Event();
panel.addMouseListener(e);
```

inside your constructor, instead of *after* that right curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

Move statement `panel.addMouseListener(e);` to the constructor `randomcolor()`. This will solve the issue.